# How to show previous input text after redirection to same page

Tags: angular

I have a search component. After inputting text in search field and on enter key press ,search will happen and it will redirect to next component lets say showComponent, where result is shown.

I want when I go back from showComponent to search component , the previous input text must be there on the input text field. How can I achieve this ?

```
<div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-text" aria-describedby="search-text" [formControl]="searchTextForm"
            placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup.enter)="searchItem(searchTextForm.value)">
            <a (click)="searchItem(searchTextForm.value)">
                <span class="search-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
        <ul *ngIf="showUl" class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li  class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let product of productName | appFilter: searchTextForm.value">
                <a (click)="searchItem(product)">{{product}}</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**EDIT:-**

I am using localStorage for storing the searched value .
And retrieving it on `ngOnInit` using `localStorage.getItem('searched');`

Now how can I show it on input field as a predefined value ?

Comment: There are many ways of doing it, like using an angular service, local storage and the best is to use NGRX store.

Comment: @BharatChoudhary I am not aware of ngrx store. Any example ?

Comment: Did you try doing `searchTextForm.setValue(localStorage.getItem('searched'))` in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook of the app?

Comment: @thisdotutkarsh yes I am able to set and retrieve as well . But how will I show it on textfield ?

Comment: Technically setting the value to the `formControlDirective` using `setValue` should set the value to the `value` of the `input` field as well. Would it be possible for you to create a working demo in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

For setting the value from the `localStorage` to `formControlDirective`, do the following in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook of the app,

```js
this.searchTextForm.setValue(localStorage.getItem('searched'));
```